Shopware How to upload binary content body
Can not pass image via file, so need directly with binary content body, I am trying the same aproach from https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c042ae0cd330f-media-management to upload media source directly but it is not working. Please can some one share more info or a screen shot how we can do the rewuest and the body.  Thanks
https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c042ae0cd330f-media-management to upload media source directly but it is not working. Please can some one share more info or a screen shot how we can do the rewuest and the body.  Thanks

Please do not post the link here. We do not intend to follow those links.

"I am trying the same aproach from [shopware url] to upload media source directly but it is not working". Define what it is not working means. Do you have errors in your code, do you have errors when you upload? If so, what errors? You tell us you did something, but don't show what you did, then you say it doesn't work, but don't say what is not working. Please, read How to ask? and post a MRE else we can't really help you. Also, please edit your question as the text is duplicated.
